# New Washing machine piping clarifications

Tags: plumbing

Edit 01/14: there will be a trap and venting accordingly on the main floor as mentioned below but missed from drawing. Location is Toronto.

We are running ABS pipes to our new washing machine on the main floor. The only option we have is to connect it to the existing 1.5" vent pipe in the basement using sanitary Tee and flexible coupling since the pipe has no room to move.
The 1.5" vent is connected to a 2" ABS pipe where a 1.5" pipe from existing washing machine and another 1.5" pipe from the kitchen sink is also connected. The 2" pipe is subsequently connected to a 4" pipe under the ground about one feet lower.

Questions we have:
First, how bad is this connection.
Second, the new pipe on the main floor will be higher than the existing vent outside. Should we add pipe to the vent so its higher than the new washing machine height.

The piping on the main floor will have its own p-trap and venting pipe.

Here is a rough drawing:[image: Rough drawing]

Another picture from construction period shows the zoomed in connection. This area is covered by a kitchen counter and sink now.

[image: zoomed in connection]

Comment: Won't pass code where I am. Too far from the top too the trap. In UPC areas, I believe the trap must be above the floor. IPC is not as restrictive, but this is **way** too much. What is **your** plumbing code in force? Wait - it also appears that you are proposing to connect without a trap at all? **That** would be acceptable nowhere.

Comment: Adding in a location would help as building codes can vary.

Comment: So the basement 1.5" vent opens up outside at ground level? This seems problematic

Comment: I'm trying to guess which would suck dry first;) Even with a trap that's a long drop in skinny pipe; likely to sound like a yeti took a water-slide. I'm wondering why the main stack isn't 4" [but idk US codes so I can't really get involved in this one, way beyond me]